# Cannot vote to leave closed for community specifc reason in Re-open Review queue

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, review-queues

When doing a reopen review, let's say for a question that was closed for being not focused and that reason was fixed, but another reason such as missing code is still present, I am not able to vote for leave closed for a community specific reason. It just says:

> You must select a reason before submitting.

I can only pick a wrong reason such as leave closed because the original close reason(s) were not resolved. This is not true and can cause confusion for the post owner.

Since this only refers to community specific reasons, I suspect this may be a site-specific issue or should this be posted on Meta anyway?

Thats what I do:

1. Click "This question doesn't meet a Geographic Information Systems Stack Exchange guidline"

[image]

2. Then the second page of close reasons appears
3. I select for example "When seeking help to debug code ..."
4. Then I click "Keep closed"
5. Then I get the error "You must select a reason before submitting"

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that when you select the "missing code" option and click "Keep Closed" it's after that you get the message about "You must select a reason before submitting"?

Comment: Not quite. I click "This question doesnt meet a ....", then "When seeking help to debug..." then "Keep closed". Then the error appears.

Comment: I encountered that error. I also tried to check the last radiobutton using down arrow key, click on it, check the reason and click on "Keep Closed", but it didn't work.

Comment: Corresponding bug report on MSO: [Reopen queue: can't choose "Leave closed" as "doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/1478931) – and on MSE: [Can not select suitable item in the Reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384634/335251)

Comment: Fixed, with more details [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422940/1328704).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @V2Blast there is a:

> Corresponding bug report on MSO: [Reopen queue: can't choose "Leave
> closed" as "doesn't meet a Stack Overflow
> guideline"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421948/1478931) – and on
> MSE: [Can not select suitable item in the Reopen
> queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384634/335251)

and:

> This is now fixed, as noted in JNat's comment. [See the MSO post for
> more details.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422940/1478931)

Comment: This is now fixed, as noted in JNat's comment. [See the MSO post for more details.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422940/1478931)